# Saving JS State to an unordered list

Tags: reactjs, components, state

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      firstName: ""
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      firstName: event.target.value
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <h1>{this.state.firstName}</h1>
      </form>
    );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Hello all, I am currently studying React and seem to be having a hard time grasping all of it. The code that I have here works in that it will show in browser what the user is typing in the input box. What I cannot seem to figure out or get to work, is mapping what is typed in the input to stay on the screen. I.e. when I hit enter, it refreshes and the name goes away. I am trying to now create an unordered list to keep each name displayed on the screen. Any help or links would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: just look at solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Just add new function (this describe what should be after submit this form) in this case You use:

> event.preventDefault() -
>
> The Event interface's preventDefault() method tells the user agent
>   that if the event does not get explicitly handled, its default action
>   should not be taken as it normally would be

---

```
onSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault()
}
```

and on form:

```
 <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
```

---

To create unordered list use something like this (credit for Robin Wieruch):

```
import React from 'react';
const initialList = [
  'Learn React',
  'Learn Firebase',
  'Learn GraphQL',
];
const ListWithAddItem = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');
  const [list, setList] = React.useState(initialList);
  const handleChange = event => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
  };
  const handleSubmit = event => {
    if (value) {
      setList(list.concat(value));
    }
    setValue('');
    event.preventDefault();
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {list.map(item => (
          <li key={item}>{item}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input type="text" value={value} onChange={handleChange} />
        <button type="submit">Add Item</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
export default ListWithAddItem;
```